# Web image as tile from local storage

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm currently trying to download an image, save it to a folder within the LocalStorage container, and then use it as tile. However, everytime I try to do so, the tile is just blank. All there is the name of the app and a title.

I'm unable to test if this occurs because the image isn't saved correctly or because the URI is incorrect.

```
var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var channelFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync(_currentChannel.Name, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

var thumbnail = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(_currentChannel.Logo));
var remoteFile = await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync("profilePicture.jpeg", new Uri(_currentChannel.Logo), thumbnail);
await remoteFile.CopyAsync(channelFolder, "profilePicture.jpeg", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

string tileXmlString = "<tile>"
+ "<visual>"
+ "<binding template='TileSquareText04'>"
+ "<image id='1' src='ms-appdata:///local/" +_currentChannel.Name + "/profilePicture.jpeg'>" + "</image>"
+ "<text id='1'>" + "Latest Image" + "</text>"
+ "</binding>"
+ "</visual>"
+ "</tile>";

Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument tileDOM = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
tileDOM.LoadXml(tileXmlString);
TileNotification tile = new TileNotification(tileDOM);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tile);
```

_currentChannel.Logo is a string with a url to a jpeg image.

I end up with a transparent tile every time.

Answer (score 1):

After the code runs, you should be able to see if the image is in your \AppData\Microsoft\Packages\\Local folder. If not, then there's a problem downloading it. If it's there, make sure it's both 200KB or less and 1024px or smaller in both dimensions. Those are the limits for tile images which, if exceeded, will cause the image to not appear. In that case you'll need to resample the image.

You should also test your tile updating code separately with a known small image, e.g. something in the package using an ms-appx URI or a remote image with an http URI. If those don't work either, then your updating code is suspect. Check for any errors or exceptions from that section of your code.